# How to make a VSCode extension partially dim code?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to build a VSCode plugin that, among other things, selectively dims code. That is:  (assuming you're in Dark Mode) all the bright blue keywords become dim blue, all the bright yellow names because dark yellow, etc. Also probably unbolds things too.

What this means is that it can draw your attention to just one part of the code, showing it in bright focus while everything else is dimmed out.

Problem is, neither Googling nor looking at the docs nor vscode/index.d.ts nor asking GPT-4 are helping me get started. At all.

I see two approaches:

1. Change the tokens of the file by either:

   1a. Setting the color of all tokens except the ones in focus to an appropriate darker color. Problem is, I can't find any API for dealing with individual tokens. I only found the `TextDocument` API, which just lets you deal with text.

   1b. Changing the semantic type of all tokens except the noes in focus to another type, and define a theme that assigns a darker color. But again, I can find no way to access the tokens. I found only the `DocumentSemanticTokensProvider`, which lets you set the tokens for a document, but not access what's already there. Nor did I find any API for getting the currently-active `DocumentSemanticTokensProvider`'s.
2. Draw a semitransparent rectangle over the out-of-focus code. But I can find no relevant API, and GPT-4 thinks none exists.

So, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution is to use the `opacity` field on the Decorator API.

```
function dimRange(startLine: number, endLine: number) {
  const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor!;
  let range = new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(startLine, 0),
                               new vscode.Position(endLine,   0));

  let decoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({opacity: '0.5'});
  editor.setDecorations(decoration, [range]);
}
```